# React: call dangerouslySetInnerHTML on state update

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble forcing a component to call `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on state update. My tests show that the state is being successfully updated and the component is rerendered. However, all the new information set on state don't show until I refresh the page again.

The only solution I found online was setting unique keys for each cell, which didn't work.

Calendar:

```
var tableItems = times.map((time) => {
  return <TableItem key={time} time={time}/>;
});
```

TableItem:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        events: []
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.events) {
        this.setState({
            events: nextProps.events
        })
    }
}

assignEvents(weedDay) {
    // Define variables based on this.state.events
    // if statement to check if event matches with time and date of table cell
            return {__html: '<div class="eventHolder">...variables...</div>'};
}

render() {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(0)}></td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(1)}></td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(2)}></td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(3)}></td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(4)}></td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(5)}></td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.assignEvents(6)}></td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Matheus Alves I created this sample project on CodeSandbox and it seems to be working. https://codesandbox.io/s/48zwkxj1n9

Is this similar to your use case? If not, could you recreate the bug that you are seeing in CodeSandbox?

Comment: Your sample is pretty similar to my use case, the only difference is that the information is coming from a parent component, so I can either set it as state using `componentWillReceiveProps` or use the props directy. The problem is that when the state/props change the component is rerendered but the method assignEvents is not called within each table cell

Comment: I would avoid using `state` in your situation. It seems like your `state` is just referring to your `props`. 

Could you recreate the bug that you are seeing in CodeSandbox? I'm not sure what could be causing it.